# How to emulate Mode 13h in a modern 3D renderer?

Tags: graphics

I was indulging in nostalgia and remembered the first game I created, which used [Mode 13h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h).

This mode was really simple to work with, since it was essentially just an array of bytes with an element for each pixel on the screen (using an indexed color scheme).

So I thought it might be fun to create something nowadays under these restrictions, but on modern hardware. The API could be as simple as:

```
public class Mode13h
{
    public byte[] VideoMemory = new byte[320 * 200];
    public Color[] Palette = new Color[256];
}
```

Now I'm wondering what would be the best way to get this data on the screen, using something like XNA / DirectX / OpenGL.

The only solution I could think of was to create a texture with the same size as the `VideoMemory` array, write the contents of `VideoMemory` to it every frame, then render that texture in a full screen quad with the correct aspect ratio and using point texture filtering for that retro look.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how Mode 13h is used.  Are you manipulating individual pixels?

Comment: @Cypher Yes, the array maps directly to the pixels on the screen. For example, using the API above, if I did `VideoMemory[323]=17` it would set the pixel at position `(3,1)` (because `323=3+1*320`) to whatever color is stored in `Palette[17]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using OpenGL I think the best way to do it is to create a texture with the size of your buffer and updating it using glTexSubImage2D. Then you just have to render a texture quad, the filtering used should be GL_NEAREST. Also be sure to disable mipmapping to gain some performance on updates.

I wanted to do the same thing and apparently this is the best way to do it with modern hardware, plus it allows easy scaling.

There is also a library made for this, PixelToaster :

http://code.google.com/p/pixeltoaster/

Comment: Yeah, that's the same thing I thought. But for instance, maybe instead of writing to the texture *every* frame, I could use a dirty flag (or a dirty rectangle) to determine *when* to update the texture. What do you think?

Comment: Keeping track of dirty flags/rectangles is probably overkill. Modern GPUs can update dozens of 320x200 textures per frame without breaking a sweat.

Comment: Even if you keep a dirty flag you would still have to update every frame when there's a lot of things happening, plus as postgoodism said a 320x200 texture update will unlikely create a speed issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way?

Not that I can think of.  In case you were keen on using XNA to do this, here's an expansion on your idea:

```
public class Mode13h {
    public RenderTarget2D VideoMemory;
    public Texture2D[] Palette;
    public Texture2D[][] Pixels;

    public Mode13h() {
        this.Palette = new Texture2D[256];
        this.Pixels = new Texture2D[320][200];
        this.VideoMemory = new RenderTarget2D( GraphicsDevice, 320, 200 );

        // initialize and populate the color palette
        foreach( Texture2D color in this.Palette) {
            color= new Texture2D( GraphicsDevice, 1, 1 );
        }
        this.Palette[0].SetData<Color>( new Color[] { Color.Black} );
        // ... do the above 255 more times :P or find some way to do it in the loop

        // initialize pixels
        for( int i = 0; i < 320; i++ ) {
            for( int j = 0; j < 200; j++ ) {
                this.Pixels[i][j] = new Texture2D( GraphicsDevice, 1, 1 );
                this.Pixels[i][j] = this.Palette[0]; // default black
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think you can already see where I'm going with this, but I'll spell it out just to be clear:

- Pre-populate `Palette` with each of the 256 colors that will be used by the game.
- `VideoMemory` is your *backbuffer* which represents an old-school 320x200 display.
- `Pixels` is a representation of each pixel on that display.

### Update Phase

After accepting input and adjusting *sprite* positions, you'll want to clear out your `Pixels` array by copying a black pixel from the `Palette` to each one of the many (many) `Pixels`.  You can then modify your `Pixels` by copying the appropriate colored pixel references from the `Palette` (probably by referencing an array of sorts from your sprites -- assuming you've *been-there-done-that*).

### Render Phase

All you have to do now is loop through all of the screen pixels in `Pixels` and draw them to `VideoMemory`, then draw `VideoMemory` to the game window / screen.  Because everything is a `Texture2D`, you can use `SpriteBatch` which makes this a bit easier.

### Possible Improvements

I'm not sure if this would help, but it might be useful to create a single texture with one pixel for each color that you want to use in your palette.  Then use that single texture to derive each one of the `Texture2D` in `Palette` by using a source rectangle.  That might improve rendering with SpriteBatch since you would in effect, have one texture.  It may even be better to store `Palette` as an array of `Rectangles`...